# Web property not returned in summary by Google Management API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-reporting-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

I use the Google management API V3 endpoint to retrieve the account summary with web properties:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries

It works fine, it returns the summary with web properties created with Google Analytics.

But there is one web property which is not returned, this web property is different than the other properties, it has been created with the new *Google Analytics V4*.

I wonder if there is some reason for not returning this one specific web property created with Google Analytic V4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google analytics GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/tag-guide) is not the same as the Old Google analytics.

The [Google Analytics reporting api v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) and the [managment api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) only works with the old type of Google analytics.  They will not return any results relating to the new type of Google Analytics.

To access data behind GA4 you need to use the [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data)

Comment: @DalmTo thank you. Is there any method in the new Analytics Data API to return the summary? (That is to do what the Management API is currently doing for the 'old' Google Analytics)

Comment: As far as i know there is nothing like that in that api yet but its still alpha it may come in the future.

Comment: Martin, you can get the summary for your properties using the new Analytics Admin API.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-admin/rest/v1alpha/accountSummaries/list